# Conditional lexer rules in Antlr4

Tags: antlr4

Given this grammar:

```
grammar ColonTest;

main        : statement* EOF;
statement   : NUM_LITERAL expression SEMICOLON;
expression  : primary (MULT_OP primary)*;
primary     : WORD+;

NUM_LITERAL : [0-9]+;
SEMICOLON   : ';';
MULT_OP     : '*' | '/'; // | ':';
WORD        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
COLON       : ':' -> skip;
```

and this input:

```
1 : statement;
2 : splitted statement
  : into two lines;
3 : a * b / c;
4 : a * b : c;
```

In the 4'th line the second colon is skipped because of the "COLON" lexer rule. But I need this colon, because its a part of the language (lets say it should be a part of the MULT_OP keyword too). How to achieve this?

### EDIT 1:

After deleting `COLON : ':' -> skip;` and inserting:

```
statement   : NUM_LITERAL ':' expression (':' expression)* SEMICOLON;
```

the tree looks like this:

[image: wrong tree]

The desired tree should look like this:

[image: desired tree]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/3UdDl9u3RVOK.png))</sub>

### EDIT 2:

How about this? Some implicit tokens defined - but for now it works.

```
grammar MultiLine;

main        : statement* EOF;
statement   : NUM_LITERAL ':' expression SEMICOLON;
expression  : primary ((MULT_OP|':') primary)*;
primary     : WORD+;

NUM_LITERAL : [0-9]+;
SEMICOLON   : ';';
MULT_OP     : '*' | '/';
WORD        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
WS2         : [\r\n]+ [ \t]+ ':' -> skip; // removes all not needed colons
WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Can I improve that code in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Tokens such as `:` should likely not be skipped.  Then, alter your `statement` rule to be:

`statement   : NUM_LITERAL expression (':' expression)* SEMICOLON;`

Comment: This doesn't fit exactly to my needs - I don't want split the expression into two parts when I have really one expression. I have edited my question (sorry for not showing images directly - not enough reputation points gained yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need a decision: either you keep the colon or you skip it. You cannot have both opposite actions at the same time. But the question is why you want to skip the colon in the first place? It doesn't hurt to have that in the parse tree, even if you don't need it after the initial number. When you later walk your parse tree you can always just ignore that token.

Comment: I could not manage to create a correct "expression" rule because the line can break in any moment - in the middle of the expression, sometimes deep in the tree. Because of that I've just wanted to remove the unnecessary colon which spitted the expression into many parts.